# Sending PUT/DELETE data with a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xml, httprequest, http-delete, http-put

I used the example from [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest/19839873#19839873) to create this JavaScript code:

```
function PostXML(webURL, post_data) {
    var objHTTP = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    objHTTP.open("POST", webURL, false);
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", post_data.length);
    objHTTP.send(post_data);

    while((objHTTP.readyState != 4) && (objHTTP.readyState != 'complete')) {
        Delay(100);
    }

    if(200 != objHTTP.Status) {
        Log.Message("Returned Status Code of: " + objHTTP.Status);
        Log.Message("Status Text: " + objHTTP.StatusText);
    }
    else {
        Log.Message("Returned Status Code of: " + objHTTP.Status);
    }

    return objHTTP.responseText;
}
```

I also need to `PUT` and `DELETE` stuff. How do I transfer this code to be able `PUT`, and how do I transfer this code to be able to `DELETE`?

Any other examples which work the same is fine too.

Comment: `var objHTTP = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");` - WHY are you using an oldIE-only method instead of the standardized `XMLHttpRequest` object every somewhat recent browser supports? And what about this horrible active waiting instead of using the `onreadystatechange` callback?

Comment: Has -5 upvotes and over 15k views.

Comment: I think here at least the tagging should make clear that it is an IE-only question.

Answer (score 16):

First of all, the code you posted is problematic and you should not be using it. See my comment on your question for some of reasons why.

To use PUT or DELETE instead of POST simply change the first argument you pass to `objHTTP.open()` to `"PUT"` or `"DELETE"`.

Answer (score 4):

You want to send PUT or DELETE instead of POST? Have you tried replacing "POST" in the code with "PUT" or "DELETE"? (it's on the 3rd line of the code you posted).

BTW - this is a really bad example of how to implement httprequests from Javascript.

Comment: Thanks! It works! See my previous comment. I'm just a very very beginner in JavaScript and used an example from the internet and adapted it. Any full examples how it should be implemented are very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code:

**Update a user**

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users";

var data = {};
data.firstname = "John2";
data.lastname  = "Snow2";
var json = JSON.stringify(data);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("PUT", url+'/12', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.onload = function () {
    var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
        console.table(users);
    } else {
        console.error(users);
    }
}
xhr.send(json);
```

**Delete a user**

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("DELETE", url+'/12', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
        console.table(users);
    } else {
        console.error(users);
    }
}
xhr.send(null);
```