# deleting a row from db using node, mysql, express and pure js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am creating a simple app using node, express, mysql.

I am trying to create a route with which I can delete a row from my db, I wrote a pure javascript xhr.

when I test it I keep getting the following error message

> POST http://localhost:3000/article/22 404 (Not Found)

this is what I have:

main.js

```
function handleDeleteClick(e, userId) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behaviour of this event (eg: submitting the form

    // Perform the AJAX request to delete this user
    var target = e.target;
    var id = target.getAttribute('data-id');
    var page = '/article/' + id;
    var parameters = 'delete=true';
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?') == true) {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                // Request completed
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", page, true);
        xmlhttp.send(parameters);
    }
}
```

and the route app.js

```
app.delete('/article/:id', function(req, res) {
    con.query(`DELETE FROM posts WHERE posts.id = ${req.params.id}`,
        function(err, result, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("deleted Record: " + result.affectedRows);
                res.redirect('/')
            }
        });
});
```

what am I missing?

help is very much appreciated!
thanks.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `POST` to `DELETE` in your `main.js`-file:

```
xmlhttp.open("DELETE", page, true);
```

You are getting this `404 NOT FOUND` error because route `POST /article/:id` does not exist (it's `DELETE /article/:id`).

> Note: Your DELETE-query is vulnerable for **SQL-injection** attacks [escaping-query-values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)

Escape query values:

```
con.query('DELETE FROM posts WHERE posts.id = ?', [req.params.id]);
```

> Note: Actually, correct http status for this case is `405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED`, but express by default doesn't distinguish those cases

Comment: thanks for all answers! I will set this one to be the 'best' answer since it is the most complete and points out most focus points. Thank you! I am aware of the vulnarability but this is for later concern since I am first getting stuff up and running on a local environment, before securing it. Much appreciated!

Comment: one questions remains, why isnt it rerouting after deletion?

Comment: @Bee I think you need to handle it on the front-end side

Comment: correct! sorry about that. Indeed this needed to be done in main.js. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`app.delete` expects to recieve a DELETE request.

`xmlhttp.open("POST", page, true);` is sending a POST request.

Change the second argument to `"DELETE"` to make a DELETE request.

Answer (score 1):

you have a delete route in your server, so if you want to send a request to that route, you should pass `"DELETE"` parameter to xmlhttp.

so simply change

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", page, true);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("DELETE", page, true);
```

also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19840685/7025986) may help you understand using `XMLHttpRequest` better

> **Do not insert params directly into your database query**
>
> As others said, you are vulnerable to SQLInjection attacks. you should evaluate params first instead of just inserting it directly into your SQL query